# How do I clarify my question?

Tags: discussion

What is the acceptable way to clarify a question you ask? EDIT: That is, one that is still new?

Comment: Edit your question. You have an 'edit' link right below it.

Comment: And do not add an answer in order to clarify it.

Comment: Your title and the body of the question are completely different.

Comment: @Servy I apologize, but being new here I did not realize there was a way to go back and edit one's question and assumed to _clarify_ my _poorly formed_ question I would either have to _repeat_ the question or try to _clarify_ it in the comments section. I don't think down-voting a question about how to ask a question should be allowed in the meta forum or is in good taste.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker George Stocker and devnull, thanks for providing a helpful, relevant answer.